# How do I stop Ubiquity running on a live USB?

Tags: 11.10, boot

I have used the USB creator and Oneiric CD image to create a live USB system.
I cannot find any way to prevent an unattended boot from the USB to avoid ubiquity.

By changing syslinux/txt.cfg I have made the default (and only) boot option "textonly" and removed "only-ubiquity".  If I interrupt the boot, choose F6 to bring up that boot parameter list and then proceed, it will boot strait into the live user.

How do I avoid ubiquity for an unattended boot?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your problem but a workaround I guess.  It will boot straight to a live session if you use an iso and grub2 to boot your usb stick.  Details from this page [How to ISO boot with Grub2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1288604)